# Refresh TabPages Pragmatically in TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have a form which contains a Tab Control which read TabPages from DataBase and add them to TabControl Pragmatically.

now, there is another form ( let's call it form2) which used to add or update these tabPages, it work well, but i need the TabPage to be bound automatically to TabControl one i click on "Save Button( which save to dataBase)" in form2.

Can i do that just from code behind without using the designer ?

This is what already done, but still not working :

```
CategoryImageIL.Images.Clear();
        MainTabs.TabPages.Clear();
        if (categories != null && categories.Count != 0)
        {

            int counter = 0;

            foreach (var cat in categories)
            {
                Image catImage = byteArrayToImage(cat.Attachment.Value);
                CategoryImageIL.Images.Add("Image" + cat.Attachment.AttachmentId.ToString(), catImage);

                TabPage tab = new TabPage();
                tab.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
                tab.BackgroundImage = null;
                tab.Size = new Size(888, 456);
                tab.Name = "Cat" + cat.CategoryId.ToString();
                tab.ImageIndex = counter;
                MainTabs.TabPages.Add(tab);
                counter++;
            }
        }
        MainTabs.SelectedIndex = 0;
        MainTabs.Refresh();
```

Thanks,

Comment: What causes this code to run?  Is this the first load of the tabs, or something that is supposed to re-load them all after Form2 does its thing?

Comment: The code is called from Form_Closing event in form2